# Get top five most repeating records in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to get top five most repeating records from a table in link to Entity Framework 4.0. How it can be possible in a single query which returns a list of collection of five records?

Comment: What exact records you are working with? How do you define they are repeating? Please, show your code. Without exact information you cannot get exact answers.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy let me explain you.. suppose i have a table of statistics in which i save a record whenever member logins to his account, now i want to get top five members which have logged in maximum times with number of their login enteries.. do u need more explaination?

Comment: That's enough for more accurate answer. But remember - next time you should provide all this information with code samples directly in question. That will make answers quick and exact

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually you should group by fields which define whether record is repeating or not. E.g. in your case it should be something like member id. Then you can introduce new range variable which will keep number of records in each group. Use that variable for ordering results:

```
var query = from s in db.Statistics
            group s by s.MemberId into g  // group by member Id
            let loginsCount = g.Count()  // get count of entries for each member
            orderby loginsCount descending // order by entries count
            select new { // create new anonymous object with all data you need
                MemberId = g.Key,
                LoginsCount = loginsCount
            };
```

Then take first 5:

```
 var top5 = query.Take(5);
```

That will generate query like

```
SELECT TOP (5)                               // Take(5)
[GroupBy1].[K1] AS [MemberId],               // new { MemberId, LoginsCount }
[GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
FROM ( SELECT
        [Extent1].[MemberId] AS [K1],
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]                     // let loginsCount = g.Count()
        FROM [dbo].[Statistics] AS [Extent1]
        GROUP BY [Extent1].[MemberId]        // group s by s.MemberId
)  AS [GroupBy1]
ORDER BY [GroupBy1].[A1] DESC                // orderby loginsCount descending
```

Comment: this seems to be helpful, thank you so much. what will be the exact query in link to entities?

Comment: @user2493843 I already updated answer with sample of generated SQL query :)

Answer (score 8):

You simply group by count, order descending by count and then Take(5).  Grouping examples, amongst others, can be found at [101 LINQ Samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b).

Comment: I did not get it, can you please suggest me the exact query?